# Remove records from two tables when value bases on dependancy

Tags: mysql

In my Opencart shop I have a lot of products with an option for color and size.
Sometimes due to importing from excel, the color option only was one value e.g. white.

I want to remote all options where the optionvalue only has one choice.

The information is stored into two tables: `oc_product_option_value` and `oc_product_option`.

For example in oc_product_option_value this looks like this:

```
product_id option_id
--------------------
66         18
66         18
66         17
67         18
67         18
67         17
```

So I want need to remove one time 66 with option 17 and one time 67 with option 17.

When I use:

```
select * from oc_product_option_value group by product_id, option_id having count(*) = 1
```

It gives me all the product_id's with only one optionvalue and I can remove it.
But I also need to remove the same product_id's from table oc_product_option.
How can I select all the products in oc_product_option which only have one optionvalue in oc_product_option_value.

I tried this but it isn't working:

```
select * from oc_product_option
where option_id IN (select product_id from oc_product_option_value group by product_id, option_id having count(*) = 1)
```

Comment: Could you report the error?

Comment: No error, just an empty result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in for `option_id`:

```
   select oc.* from oc_product_option oc
INNER JOIN (
select option_id,product_id from oc_product_option_value group by product_id, option_id having count(*)=1
) t on t.option_id=oc.option_id AND t.product_id =oc.product_id
```

Comment: Nope. Got an error:


select * from oc_product_option
where option_id IN (select option_id from oc_product_option_value group by product_id, option_id having count(*) ORDER BY `product_id` ASC 
 LIMIT 0, 25

Comment: It's getting me to much results. With

`select * from oc_product_option where product_id in (select product_id from oc_product_option_value group by product_id, option_id having count(option_id) = 1)`

I also get to much result but I believe it has to be something like this.

For example, in oc_product_option_value I get 614 rows. In oc_product_option with last mentioned code I get 970 rows. The also include the option_id's which are counted more than once.

Comment: Gives me less results, it's close but it gives wrong results.
For example. product_id 69 has 5x option_value 18 and 1x option value 17.
In my first command, it returns the product_id with option_id 17.
In your latest suggestion it returns 18.

Comment: Yes!! That gives me the same results as the first query.
I'm not a programmer (not even close) but I can "read" and understand the query's. But your last suggestion, I do not understand. But it is working. So I'm glad.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

OK this bring me a little closer:

```
select * from oc_product_option where product_id in (select product_id from oc_product_option_value group by product_id, option_id having count(option_id) = 1)
```

This gives me all the correct product_id BUT show me the product_id with all the option_id's. Not just the ones that are single.